# CKEditor plugin to change the default margin of selected paragraphs and lists at the same time

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am writing a CKEditor plugin to achieve the following: By default, the `<p>` and `<ul>` tags introduce a default margin which is not 0. I want to override this behavior and let the user upon pressing a button on the toolbar, to set the margin of selected paragraphs and/or lists to 0.

For example lets say we have the following content:
[image: default margin of paragraphs and lists]

which translates in the following html:

[image: html code]

The plugin code (plugin.js) I wrote so far is:

```
( function() {
    CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'nomargin', {
        icons: 'nomargin',
        init: function( editor ) {
            editor.addCommand( 'nomargin', {
                                                exec: function( editor ) {
                                                    var style = new CKEDITOR.style( editor.config.nomargin_style );
                                                    editor.focus();
                                                    editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );
                                                    editor['applyStyle']( style );
                                                    editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );
                                                }
                                            } );
            editor.ui.addButton( 'NoMargin', {
                label: 'No Margin',
                command: 'nomargin'
            });
        }
});
})();

CKEDITOR.config.nomargin_style = {
    element: ['p', 'ul'],
    styles: { 'margin': '0'}
};
```

My problem is that it works as long as I select each paragraph or unordered list one at a time. If I select both paragraph and list, the style will not apply. Even if I select only elements of the same tag (e.g. 2 paragraphs) the style will not apply. I have to select one at a time, press the plugin button, then select the next paragraph or list press the plugin button again etc. This can be confusing since the margin of two elements overlaps, so in order to get the desired result one has first to select the top paragraph press the button, (no result yet), then select the list and press the button to achieve the following:

[image: desired result]

[image: html code]

Can somebody show me the way to achieve this with a single press on the plugin button?